# How To Spiralize Mesh

Tags: mesh

I wanted to turn the selected mesh in the image into a spiral. Is there any way I could do this? I couldn't do it with the screw modifier. Thanks! :)

[image]

Comment: I'm confused;

1: You have a mesh selected, not an image
2: It's... already pretty much a spiral...

Comment: @AlexanderESmith I know that I have a mesh selected, you must've read the description wrong as it's not an image I'm trying to select. Also, the mesh is just a screw, I want to turn it into a spring shape.

Comment: I see. Can you elaborate on what you consider the difference to be between a spring and what you see here? A higher frequency of repetition in the pattern? A single pipe rather than the two? A thinner pipe (so they don't touch)?

Comment: @AlexanderESmith I consider this to be more of a rope. With a spring I expect it to be like this: https://d27ucmmhxk51xv.cloudfront.net/media/english/illustration/spring.jpg?version=1.2.1 but pretend that the spring is the same shape but made out of the "rope".

Comment: If you want to use the current rope, I'd need to know how you created it. Otherwise I can tell you how I'd make a spring from scratch.

Comment: @AlexanderESmith Yes, I'd like to possibly change the rope into a spring. Here's an example I managed to find: https://prevuepet.com/images/products/productaddl_730_1445_0_resized_26486_zoom.jpg just take away the ends and make it a bit cleaner.

Comment: @AlexanderESmith Oh, ok. Is it possible to check the settings of a modifier you already applied?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Unless you can undo past that point?

Comment: I would, but sadly that was one of the first parts I made. I'll try making a replica instead.

Comment: I've messed around with the settings and the closest I could get with the screw modifier was 4m for the Screw, Y for the Axis, 3 Iterations and everything else stays the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106061/discussion-between-mmmchezburgerz-and-alexanderesmith).